# Writing a function to find a triangular number in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I couldn't find an answer by searching and I've been working on this for two days and am stumped. I think I am just confused on the math. I am trying to write a function that finds the first n triangular numbers.

```
def formula(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        print i, '\t', n * (n + 1)/ 2
        i += 1
    print
```

So for example if I type in formula(5) it would look like this:

```
 1       1
 2       3
 3       6
 4       10
 5       15
```

I got how to make a table going from 1 through whatever number I choose n.. but I can't figure out how to make the second part equal the formula I typed in which would be n*(n+1)/2. What is the logic going through this? Everytime I type in formula(5) for example the loop goes from 1-5 but returns the same exact answer in the right hand column all the way down which would be 15. I can't make it to where it would start at 1, 3, 6 etc on the right hand side.

Comment: The line should be `print i, '\t', i * (i + 1)/ 2`, `i` instead of `n`.

Comment: wow.. I feel really dumb for such a small mistake. I don't think I will ever get to an advanced level but I really do love coding even if I suck at it. But it did work. It actually makes a little bit more sense..

Comment: Getting better as a programmer means getting quicker at spotting and correcting mistakes, not necessarily making fewer mistakes. Also, try to make new mistakes, it's the best you can hope for (c:

Answer (score 2):

The comment that observed that you are computing `n * (n + 1) / 2` instead of `i * (i + 1) / 2` is correct. You can also get rid of having to do a multiplication and division at each step by observing that the i-th triangle number is simply the sum of the integers from 1 to i, so at each step you just have to add i to the previous triangle number. Code below:

```
def formula(n):
    ith_sum = 0
    for i in xrange(1, n+1):
        ith_sum += i
        print i, '\t', ith_sum
```

Answer (score 0):

I had completely forgotten about triangular numbers, thank you for the question!  I am glad you now know the correct solution. I was curious if it could be done a different way:

```
def triangular(number):
    return number + triangular(number-1) if number else 0

print triangular(5)
```

If you fancy a challenge, you could try and work this out. A print statement here and there would help you spot what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution that worked for me

```
 def print_triangular_numbers(n):
    for i in range(n+1):
        print(i, int(i * (i + 1)/ 2))
       
print_triangular_numbers(5)
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not the answer to this question. So delete it as soon as you read it.

It is the answer for printing

```
#
##
###
####
#####
######
```

on the console.

Follwing is the code for it :

```
var strng="";
    for (var i=1; i<7; i++)
    {
        for (var j=1; j<=i; j++)
        {
           strng=strng+"#";
        }
        strng=strng+"\n";
    }

    console.log(strng);
```